# Freeing a pointer by dereferencing a doublepointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, free

I'm trying to write a function which will free a dynamically allocated string by sending the address of the string (char*) to the function. (Sending char**)

I have tried doing it like this:

```
void dstring_delete(DString* stringToDelete)
{
    // Precondition: stringToDelete is not NULL

    assert(stringToDelete != NULL);

    free(*stringToDelete);
```

Where DString is defined like this:

```
typedef char* DString;
```

The call to the function looks like this:

```
dstring_delete(&str1);
```

Where str1 is of type DString:

```
DString str1, str2;
```

I cant seem to figure out what is going wrong but this assert below the function call fails:

```
assert(str1 == NULL);
```

So my question is how I properly free the memory in this instance.

I have tried different arguments sent to the free function and also tried to find the same issues here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. When and where do you initialize `str1`? What do you make it point to? Where do you do the `assert(str1 == NULL)` that you claim fail?

Comment: After `free(*stringToDelete);`, add `*stringToDelete = NULL;`.

Comment: "strings" in C are already pointers.  You shouldn't need the `&` operator when you call `dstring_delete(&str1);`

Comment: @RobertHarvey It seems the OP is emulating pass by reference, by passing pointers to the variables. I suppose the OP is supposed to assign `NULL` to the original pointers as suggested by Ian Abbott.

Comment: A "double pointer" points to a value of type `double`.   A "pointer to pointer" points to a pointer.

Comment: Marcus, also please Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There's nothing in the [documentation for free()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) to indicate that there should be any expectation that `str1` should contain `null` after the `free()` call.  In fact, `str1` is effectively *undefined* after `free()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `str1` is pointing to an allocated block that is to be freed and that the code sequence to free the block is like this:

```
    dstring_delete(&str1);
    assert(str1 == NULL);
```

OP's implementation of `dstring_delete` seems to be as follows, but OP did not post the full function definition including the closing brace:

```
void dstring_delete(DString* stringToDelete)
{
    // Precondition: stringToDelete is not NULL

    assert(stringToDelete != NULL);

    free(*stringToDelete);
}
```

It is not very clear from OP's question, but I think their code contains the following sequence, with `str1` pointing to a previously allocated block to be freed:

```
    dstring_delete(&str1);
    assert(str1 == NULL);
```

OP wrote that the `assert(str1 == NULL);` was failing. This is because `dstring_delete` does not change the value of `*stringToDelete` (which aliases the `str1` variable) so `*stringToDelete` (and the `str1` variable) will still contain a non-null value on return from the function. However, the `assert(str1 == NULL);` implies that it is expecting `dstring_delete` to set the pointer value to `NULL`. That is easily fixed by changing the function body of `dstring_delete` to set the pointer to `NULL` after freeing the allocated block:

```
void dstring_delete(DString* stringToDelete)
{
    // Precondition: stringToDelete is not NULL

    assert(stringToDelete != NULL);

    free(*stringToDelete);

    *stringToDelete = NULL;
}
```

Now, after the function call `dstring_delete(&str1);`, `str1` will be `NULL` so the `assert(str1 == NULL);` call will pass.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name of a string is itself a memory reference to the string; the type is char pointer and so the variable contains a pointer, which is a memory address. So when you call free() you only have to pass it the name of the variable.
(If you use the "&" you are passing the memory address where the string's memory address is located, and you only need the latter.)